# Send raw bulkmail using aws ses ApI interface(Empty required header 'To'.)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

Hi I am trying to send bulkmail with attachment using amazon ses. I can able to send mails with attachment but my to-mails are appearing for all the users that I have send. I am trying to add those destination mails in bcc fields but it is throwing an error `Empty required header 'To'`.
This is what I've already tried:

```
private static BodyBuilder GetMessageBody()
{
var body = new BodyBuilder()
{
    HtmlBody = @"<p>Amazon SES Test body</p>",
    TextBody = "Amazon SES Test body",
};
body.Attachments.Add(@"G:\me.jpg");
return body;
}

private static MimeMessage GetMessage()
{
   var message = new MimeMessage();

List<string> to = new List<string>(50);
to.Add("xxxxxx@gmail.com");
to.Add("xxxxxx@gmail.com");

message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["senderaddress"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["senderaddress"]));

for (int i = 0; i < to.Count; i++)
{
    message.Bcc.Add(new MailboxAddress(string.Empty,to[i]));

    //message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(string.Empty, "xxxxx@gmail.com"));
//message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(string.Empty, "xxxxxx@gmail.com"));

}



message.Subject = "Amazon SES Test";
message.Body = GetMessageBody().ToMessageBody();
return message;
}

private static MemoryStream GetMessageStream()
{
var stream = new MemoryStream();
GetMessage().WriteTo(stream);
return stream;
}

private void SendEmails()
{
var credentals = new BasicAWSCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretAccessKey"]);

using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentals, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
{
    var sendRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest { RawMessage = new RawMessage(GetMessageStream()) };
    try
    {
        var response = client.SendRawEmail(sendRequest);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 1 email address in to 'To' field. Perhaps send the email to yourself and add the others as a BCC.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the BCC header to send out bulk mails, IMHO you should send one email with a clear "to" header to each of the recipients. So instead looping through recipients and adding them to BCC you should rather create and send a message there.